# Animación de gráficos de barras en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Necesito crear un vídeo (o gif) que muestre la venta de distintos productos a lo largo del tiempo, y a medida que el tiempo avance el ingreso en ventas aumente para cada producto.

Esta representación la necesito en un gráfico de barras horizontal, y a su vez las posiciones de las barras se vayan modificando según la posición en cuanto a las ventas de cada uno.

Ej:

```
Enero2019
Producto A -> $100
Producto B -> $90
Producto C -> $50

Febrero2019
Producto B -> $160
Producto A -> $150
Producto C -> $90

Marzo2019
Producto C -> $200
Producto A -> $190
Producto B -> $160
```

Comment: Bienvenido Ignacio Calderón a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Trata de mejorar tu pregunta agregando lo que hayas intentado/investigado hasta ahora,. Saludos.

Comment: Existe un paquete para animar que se basa en `ggplot2`, se llama [gganimate](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate) asimismo está disponible en el CRAN `install.packages('gganimate')`

Answer (score 1):

El codigo permite crear esa figura gif

```
dts=data.frame(Mes=c("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril"), A=c(100,160,200,250),
               B=c(90,150,190,200),C=c(50,90,160,150))
library(animation)

saveGIF({ # i=1 
  for (i in 1:nrow(dts)) barplot(as.numeric(dts[i,-1]),names.arg=colnames(dts)[-1],
                                 col=c("darkblue","red","green"),main=dts[i,1],horiz = T)
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]